# Store data in one SQLite table, then retrieve and store it into another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am learning how to use the SQLite database, and I have a problem storing data in a table, and then later on retrieving it and storing into a new table.

I have created my first table (FoodType) as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE FoodType(
    type_id integer,
    Category_id integer,
    Type text,
    Quantity text,
    NumberCalories text
)
```

I retrieve data from this table in a view controller and display the data in labels. Now I want to store the data into another table (Order) which I have created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE Order (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    type-meal text,
    Quantity text,
    NumCal text
)
```

This is the code I am trying to use to insert data into the second table:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
    @"INSERT INTO Order (type-meal,Quantity,NumCal) VALUES (\"%@\",\%@\",\"%@\")",_typeLbl.text,_Quantity.text,_Number.text];
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What error are you getting?

Comment: Please show the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

"Order" is a reserved word in SQL.  Try calling the table something else.

Comment: Thank u trojanfoe, i rename to SavedD but i didn't  got value

Answer (score 1):

try to use the property "REPLACE INTO" instead of "INSERT INTO"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `-` characters in identifiers without quoting them.

Try `type_meal` or `"type-meal"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is all my code which i use to save data in the second tableView which have the type of category, there is nothing store in database but if i determine the type_id=4 it take the fourth type of the first category only:
 - (IBAction)SaveData:(id)sender {
    @try {
        if (sqlite3_open([[AppDelegate getDBPath] UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK) {

```
          NSString *statement= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO SavedD (type_meal,Quantity,NumCal) SELECT Type,Quantity,NumberCalories FROM FoodType Where type_id=?" ];
         const char *sqlstatement = [statement UTF8String];

                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Data inserted Successfully");
                    //  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"OK" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    // [alert show];

                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [mealType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [Quantit UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [NumofCal UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                    NSLog(@"%@",mealType);
                    //   NSLog(@"%@",PersonId);
                    NSLog(@"%@",Quantit);
                    NSLog(@"%@",NumofCal);

                    int iResult = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                    NSLog(@"%d",iResult);
                    if (SQLITE_DONE!=iResult )
                        NSAssert1(0,@"Error when inserting  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                }
                else {

                    UIAlertView *AlertOK = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data not inserted22" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [AlertOK show];

                }

                sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }



        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"The Record already inserted");
        }
```

}

After check the Data inserted Successfully..But the values of "mealType","Quantit" and "NumofCal" are null..